# pandas series drop when multiindex is not unique

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ABC'), np.arange(3)])
s = pd.Series(1, midx)
s

A  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
B  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

It is very convenient to use `drop` to get rid of cross sections.  For example

```
s.drop('A')

B  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

But if I make the index non-unique

```
s = s.append(pd.Series(0, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 2)]))).sort_index()
s

A  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   2    0
B  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

Then the same `drop` no longer works.

```
s.drop('A')

A  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   2    0
B  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

How do I drop like before

The desired result should be (this doesn't work, what does)

```
s.drop('B')

A  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   2    0
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `s.drop('B')` doesn't work but using the `level=0` parameter does.

```
s.drop('B', level=0)

A  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   2    0
C  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
dtype: int64
```